# Deploy C# client application (S3) with Amazon AWS secret key?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, secret-key

I've written my *hello world* AWS program today - simple file upload to a premade S3 bucket.

In the context of this program deployed to a client desktop (for arguments sake), is my Secret Access Key safe?

`using (AmazonS3Client a = new AmazonS3Client("MyAccessKey", "MySecretAccessKey"))
            {`

```
            foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
            {
                TransferUtilityUploadRequest tr = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName("test_mydomain_com")
                .WithFilePath(((FileInfo)lvi.Tag).FullName)
                .WithTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
                TransferUtility tu = new TransferUtility(a);

                tu.Upload(tr);

                MessageBox.Show("Win!");
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no - not really.  See this question [Storing My Amazon Credentials in C# Desktop App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161022/storing-my-amazon-credentials-in-c-desktop-app) which expands on why and what you can do about it.

Comment: So: 

send operation name to my web service that holds my secret key, 

which returns a hashed signature for the operation, 

and carry on from there using that signature.